# CodeIgniter MySQL Dynamic sized Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to be able to take in an array of constraints that I can use in my query. When I use a foreach loop such as

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('items');
foreach($tags_array as $tag)
{
    $this->db->where('tag_id', $tag);
}
```

I noticed it only uses the last assigned value of tag_id in the array. I was wondering if there was any way around this.

I forgot to mention I want this be a "AND WHERE" clause as well.

Thanks!

Comment: u are overwriting the `where` part ,so thats why its getting only the last value , use `array` instead of `$tag`.

Comment: also u will get something like this `... WHERE tag_id = value1 AND tag_id = value2 ..` , i think that u need to use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: When I tried 
$this->db->where('tag_id', $tags_array);
I still get an error.

Comment: `$tags_array` should be a key value pair

Comment: I was able to get a result from $this->db->where($tags_array) but I'm still getting the same result where it's only using the last value

Comment: can you update your Q with exact mysql query ,

Comment: SELECT `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` FROM (`tags_recipes`) JOIN `recipes` ON `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` = `recipes`.`recipe_id` JOIN `tags` ON `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` IN (3)

Comment: I want it to instead look something like SELECT `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` FROM (`tags_recipes`) JOIN `recipes` ON `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` = `recipes`.`recipe_id` JOIN `tags` ON `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` =  $tag1 AND WHERE 'tags_recipes'.'tag_id' = $tag2    instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('items');
$tag_condition = array();
foreach($tags_array as $tag)
{
      $tag_condition[]   = $tag;
}

$this->db->where_in('tag_id', $tag_condition);
```

Ho wabout using this

Comment: It still only uses the last entry in $tag_condition

Comment: try using echo $this->db->last_query and run it in phpmyadmin , navicate or sql yog to test. Others ids you provide may not exist in the db therefore it is fetching only the last one which is found

Comment: SELECT `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` FROM (`tags_recipes`) JOIN `recipes` ON `tags_recipes`.`recipe_id` = `recipes`.`recipe_id` JOIN `tags` ON `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `tags_recipes`.`tag_id` IN (3)

Comment: That's what it is running. I want the WHERE to be an AND clause

Comment: it is rediculous to say where tags_recipes.tag_id = 1 and tags_recipes.tag_id = 2 and tags_recipes.tag_id = 3. It is bound to take the last one. You should use OR or Where in.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this create a function in your model and pass all the tag_ids in an array to that function by using your controller......

```
$result = $this->model_name->function_name_in_model($tag_ids);
```

In model use it in where condition using IN in sql........you will get correct result.

```
select id from items where id IN($tag_ids);
```